# WPF binding to a Usercontrol and getting an error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

Im starting with WPF, sorry if i cant explain well, and i have hours trying to solve how to bind a collection to a custom grid is named PagingDataGrid.

The PagingDataGrid is in CustomerSearchControl binding GridItems to ItemsSource, when i excecute SearchCommand GridItems gets updated but nothing else changes.

I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'GridItems' property not found on 'object' ''PagingDataGridViewModel' (HashCode=54151655)'. BindingExpression:Path=GridItems; DataItem='PagingDataGridViewModel' (HashCode=54151655); target element is 'PagingDataGrid' (Name='Me'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

CustomerSearchControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Namespace.CustomerSearchControl"
             ... >
    <Control.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="CustomerSearchViewModel" ... />
    </Control.DataContext>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <GroupBox Header="Registros">
            <controls:PagingDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" Height="300" />
        </GroupBox>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>


public class CustomerSearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<GridItem> GridItems{ get; set; }
    public ICommand SearchCommand { get; set; }

    public CustomerSearchViewModel()
    {
        GridItems = new ObservableCollection<GridItem>();
        SearchCommand = new RelayCommand(SearchEntities, () => true);
    }
}
```

PagingDataGrid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Namespace.PagingDataGrid" x:Name="Me"
             ... >
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding Path="PagingDataGridViewModel" ... />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
       ...
        <xcdg:DataGridControl 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=ItemsSource}" Grid.Row="0"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>


public partial class PagingDataGrid : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(PagingDataGrid),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable)));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You need to declare instance of `CustomerSearchViewModel` in XAML and bind to DataContext.</s>

This is how to do it:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <local:CustomerSearchViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Make sure to declare namespace `local` at root i.e. at UserControl:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication" <-- Replace WpfApplication with
                                             actual namespace of your ViewModel.
```

**Not needed since getting instance from ServiceLocator.**

---

And for binding to `GridItems` you need to bind explicitly to `CustomerSearchControl` DataContext using `RelativeSource`. This is needed because you have explicitly set DataContext on `PagingDataGrid` to `PagingDataGridViewModel`. So, it will search for `GridItems` property in PagingDataGridViewModel instead of CustomerSearchViewModel.

```
<controls:PagingDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.GridItems, 
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                               AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

Or you can give `x:Name` to `CustomerSearchControl` and bind using `ElementName`.

Comment: I have the instance provided by a Locator: <Binding Path="CustomerSearchViewModel" Source="{StaticResource Locator}" />

Comment: @Najera - Ok great. Then you have to do second thing which i just updated in answer to get it working.

Comment: I got almost the same error: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'GridItems' property not found on 'object' ''PagingDataGridViewModel' (HashCode=54151655)'. BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.GridItems; DataItem='PagingDataGrid' (Name='Me'); target element is 'DataGridControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Answer (score 1):

never set the datacontext of your usercontrol to self.
so simply remove

```
 <UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="PagingDataGridViewModel" ... />
 </UserControl.DataContext>
```

EDIT:
if you not remove this, then your

```
<UserControl x:Class="Namespace.PagingDataGrid" x:Name="Me">
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="PagingDataGridViewModel" ... />
  </UserControl.DataContext>
  <Grid>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=ItemsSource}" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

datacontext for your usercontrol is PagingDataGridViewModel and if PagingDataGridViewModel dont have a property ItemsSource you get an error. you never get the GridItems from your CustomerSearchViewModel that you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but im using Locator from MVVM Light Toolkit.